# Javascript unsure about s+=1 - Why it alerts 5 not 1, as what is s equal to in the s=s+1

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, increment, var

I'm not sure how the `s+=1` works, i know it's `s=s+1`, but am unsure work it alerts 5 as i assumed it would be 1. Thanks

```
var s=0; 

for(i=0;i<=8;i++)    

 if((i%2)==0)s+=1; 

alert(s);
```

Comment: It will add 1 to s when i is 0, 2, 4, 6, & 8 - therefore s == 5.

Comment: Why did you assume it would be 1?

Comment: If you want to have an alert each time you increment s, you'll need to put curly braces around the code you want inside your for-loop. Otherwise, the alert is only happening once after the loop is complete.

Comment: What do you *expect* the output to be. *Why*? When you step through this executing code in a debugger, where does it first deviate from that expectation? (If you don't know how to step through with a debugger, that's a great next step in your study.) When that happens, what operation was performed? What did you think the result would be? What was the result? When you look up the documentation on that operation, what do you find?

Comment: Thanks sorry for silly question just started learning thanks for advice and help!

Answer (score 1):

Sometime best way to understand is reading line by line or debugging or writing variable values..

In your case it will loop 8 times and `if((i%2)==0)` for every `even` value of i it will increment `s` so it will print 5 as you have 5 even values for that loop

```js
var s=0;

for(i=0;i<=8;i++)

if((i%2)==0){
s+=1;
console.log(s);
}

alert(s);
```